# how I can write this equation ?

Tags: math-mode

how i do this equation in the **circle red*?

[image]

Comment: A simple google search gives: http://tex.wikidot.com/snippets:overset-and-underset   you may have to adjust the size of your overset symbol.

Comment: Load the `amsmath` package to access the `\overset` macro, and then write (while in math mode, obviously) `\overset{*}{\varepsilon}` and `\overset{*}{u}`.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}
\newcommand{\Underbar}[1]{\underaccent{\bar}{#1}}
\newcommand{\ubar}{\underbar u}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\Underbar{\Underbar\varepsilon} =
\frac{1}{2}  (\accentset{*}{\ubar})
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```